# I4GL Loop query

Tags: informix, 4gl

I am trying to solve this issue for last couple of days, but no idea how to do it. What I am trying is to get 3 records from a <s>column</s> table. If any Informix 4GL gurus are out there I need some help please.

```
        declare s_curs cursor for
          SELECT * FROM crcharge
                WHERE chargenum IN
                 (SELECT shtwrd_no FROM crbookid WHERE crbookid.book_no = rpt.book_no)

                  let chgkey_count = 1
            FOREACH s_curs into z_charge.*
                  let t_col = 15
               if  chgkey_count <= 3 then
                  let chgkey_count = chgkey_count + 1
                  let chgkey_count = t_chgkey
                  let scratch = z_charge.chgkey
                  let rpt.chgkey = scratch
                  call make_charge_section(scratch) returning rpt.chgkey
                  print
                     column 1, ESC, "&a15.5R",ESC,"&a12C", rpt.chgkey #t_col+2 ,

               end if
            END FOREACH
```

Comment: Struggling to see what this is about but this let chgkey_count = chgkey_count + 1 followed by let chgkey_count = t_chgkey, sort of leapt out of the code..

Comment: Your terminology is suspect; you can't get records from a column, but you can from a table.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the line that I've commented out in the following (mild) revision of the code:

```
DECLARE s_curs CURSOR FOR
    SELECT * FROM crcharge
     WHERE chargenum IN
           (SELECT shtwrd_no FROM crbookid WHERE crbookid.book_no = rpt.book_no)

LET chgkey_count = 0
FOREACH s_curs INTO z_charge.*
    IF chgkey_count >= 3 THEN
        EXIT FOREACH
    END IF
    LET chgkey_count = chgkey_count + 1
    --LET chgkey_count = t_chgkey        -- Probable problem
    LET scratch = z_charge.chgkey
    LET rpt.chgkey = scratch
    CALL make_charge_section(scratch) RETURNING rpt.chgkey
    PRINT COLUMN 1, ESC, "&a15.5R",ESC,"&a12C", rpt.chgkey
END FOREACH
```

And I think I would simplify the code even more by writing:

```
LET chgkey_count = 0
FOREACH s_curs INTO z_charge.*
    IF chgkey_count >= 3 THEN
        EXIT FOREACH
    END IF
    LET chgkey_count = chgkey_count + 1
    LET rpt.chgkey = make_charge_section(z_charge.chgkey)
    PRINT COLUMN 1, ESC, "&a15.5R",ESC,"&a12C", rpt.chgkey
END FOREACH
```

Comment: I tried but I think we are missing something, also i may post it on IIUG. Thank you.

Comment: I agree, but you've not said what's going wrong, really.  For example, have you tried to DISPLAY key data (like `chgkey_count` and `z_charge.chkkey`) at points in the code?  Is the FOREACH being executed too often, or not often enough?  Is the SELECT going to return anything?  Is there a condition missing from the SELECT?  Can you show sample data for the tables; can you show enough of the table schemas to support the sample data?

Comment: Right now it is printing like this 34CC 2539(4a) the result suppose to print like this CC 259(4), CC 253(a). Thank you

Comment: Strip out the escape codes and see what it prints without them.  That is, remove the two references to ESC and the two literal strings; the COLUMN 1 isn't doing much either.  So, try `PRINT "<<", rpt.chgkey, ">>"` (or, if you prefer, leave off the string literals).  See what you get.  If you're not get the right output, then either the wrong data is being fetched or the `make_charge_section()` function is screwing things up.  Use DISPLAY statements to debgug what is happening (if reports allow DISPLAY statements; AFAICR, they do).  Or use the I4GL Interactive Debugger if you have it.